# How do you clone an element's NamedNodeMap to an empty object?

Tags: javascript, html, object, clone

I have a javaScript array of objects, where the objects are called **text**, where each object element contains information about an HTML element that looks like the following using the Chrome browser's inspect Source Watch area:

```
text:
  attributes: NamedNodeMap
                0: baseURI: "file:.../awesomplete_textarea.html"
                   childNodes: NodeList []
                   firstChild: null
                   isConnected: false
                   lastChild: null
                   localName: "label"
                   name: "label"
                   namespaceURI: null
                   nextSibling: null
                   nodeName: "label"
                   nodeType: 2
                   nodeValue: "Alternative Rock"
                   ownerDocument: document
                   ownerElement: li
                   parentElement: null
                   parentNode: null
                   prefix: null
                   previousSibling: null
                   specified: true
                   textContent: "Alternative Rock"
                   value: "Alternative Rock"
                   __proto__: Attr }
              length: 1
              label: { same content as 0, above }
              __proto__: NamedNodeMap }
  label: "Alternative Rock"
  tagName: "LI"
  value: "Alternative Rock (Alternative)"
  length: 16
  __proto__: String
```

Note: While the ***attributes*** member of **text** object (above) only contains the information for the *label* attribute, it could also contain other attributes items, such as a style and/or class, which were copied from a set of `<li>` tags in my web-page, in which case there would be additional entries in the **text** object and ***attributes*** member for those attributes items.

When the information `<li>` tags are collected, the tag's attributes are copied into **text** object using the copyAttributes function that is shown below, which works fine.

However, when later try to use the same copyAttributes function to copy the **text**.***attributes*** to the **attr** variable to then create a new HTML element, I get this error:

```
mycode.js:98 Uncaught TypeError: to.setNamedItem is not a function
  at copyAttributes (mycode.js:98)
  at Function._.ITEM (mycode.js:940)
  at _.item (mycode_textarea.html:625)
  at mycode.js:826
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at _.evaluate (mycode.js:825)
```

The following code shows how this call is made, and what I'm trying to with the information copied into **attr** object variable.

```
function copyAttributes( from, to ) {
  var attr;

  for( const [ key, value ] of Object.entries( from ) ) {

    if( !isNaN( key ) ) {  // Only add the named attributes ...

      let name = from[ key ].name;;  // get the attribute's name

      if( to[ name ] === undefined ) {

        attr       = document.createAttribute( name ); // Create the attribute.
        attr.value = value.value;                      // Assign its value.

        to.setNamedItem( attr );                       // Add it to to

      }

    }

  }

}

var tagName = 'li';
var attribute = {};

// Copy the text.attributes from the text object to attributes.

copyAttributes( text.attributes, attributes );

// Add the information in the {...} object to the attributes object ...

Object.assign( attributes,
               attributes,
               { innerHTML: label,             // Add these to those just copied.
                 'role':    'option',
                 'id':      'list_' + this.count +
                            '_item_' + item_id,
                 'value':   value } );

// Create the new `<li>` with the original tag's attributes and those added, above.

$.create( tagName, attributes );
```

The problem seems to be that the `to` parameter of the copyAttributes function isn't the **NamedNodeMap** type, so it doesn't support the `setNamedItem` method.

How can I create an empty ***attributes*** variable of this type?

Or is there a better/easier way to populate the ***attributes*** variable with the **test**.***attributes*** information?

Thanks.

Comment: This sure sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)  . What is your goal? Forget copying attributes and tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My web-page uses <li> tags to specify possible choices for a user to choose from in a hidden <ul> tag list, and the attributes of these <li> tags are copied into an array of objects.  Then when a user types comma separated values into a textbox to find a sub-set of the original <li>s, the individual comma delimited values are compared with the values in the objects of array, and matches are used to build new <li> tags in another <ul> list.  The difference between the two lists is that the second adds additional information and formatting attributes to what was found in the source <li> tags.

Comment: I brought up copying attributes because I'm using the awesomplete library which creates a searchable drop-down list from which the user can select values by entering comma delimited values into a textarea element or click on matching values in a drop-down list. It creates an array from the <li> tag list, searches them, and creates a new list of <li> tags.  However, I want to modify these <li> tags by combining additional information and formatting attributes with what was found in original <li> tag's.

Comment: I'm unlikely to convince you, but your approach is flawed for various reasons. For example, `var attribute = {}` will never create NamedNodeMap with a method named `setNameId`, in your call to `Object.assign()` you set add a `value` while you've already cloned it fro the attributes object you just created. It would be much simpler to create `li` tags in a factory function. Why? The `namedNodeMap` of two `LI` are practically idenitical to begin with.

Comment: True on the 'var attribute = {}'. Which is why I asked about creating such an object.  As to value, it is the attribute that awesomplete looks for to find matches, but the cloned value may not be the one I want, so I set it with the value I need.  As to the namedNodeMap of the two 
 <li>s being almost identical, that's possible, but not necessarily in every <li>. Some have added information and formatting that other won't have, also every <li> has a unique value and label value for the user to select from.  By the way how are you graying your code samples in your comments?  factory function?

Comment: And wouldn't the factory function also need to 'know' how to create a namedNodeMap in order to merge the additional information and formatting needed for the second list?

Comment: By the way, thanks for trying to convince me and addressing the issues you see in my question.

Comment: A factory function only needs to know about the additional attributes/values for each `li`. the `NamedNodeMap` is an interface - meaning it has no constructor - meaning the objects in that based upon them are internally generated. You don't need a `NamedNodeMap` at all.

Comment: [Comment styles](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: l suspect the only thing you actually need out of all of that is `.value`. The attributes are a reflection of the element's state and most of them come about by how they are situated in the document.

Comment: Would you please give me a good search for factory function so I can read more in depth about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/mdrqRjB) of a working version of the drow-down combobox that properly created the li tag elements and copies the desired attributes into it.

This create function is from the Awesomplete plug-in, but it tha been modified to not set the focud on the newly created element.

```
$.create = function( tag, o ) {
  var element = document.createElement( tag );

  for( var i in o ) {
    var val = o[ i ];

    if( i === 'inside' ) {
      $( val ).appendChild( element );
    }
    else if( i === 'around' ) {

      var ref = $( val );

      ref.parentNode.insertBefore( element, ref );
      element.appendChild( ref );

      if( ref.getAttribute( 'autofocus' ) != null ) {
        ref.focus();
      }
    }
    else if( i in element ) {
      element[ i ] = val;
    }
    else {
      element.setAttribute( i, val );
    }
  }

  return element;
};
```

This is my modified code that calls the above create function and assign the attributes.

```
if( tagName === 'LI' ) {

  matched = ( inputValue = ( ', ' +
                             me.input.value.trim().toLowerCase() +
                             ',' ) )    // Normalize input.value so that the first item can be found.
                           .includes( ', ' + value.toLowerCase() + ',' ) ||         // Find the normalized value in the normalized input.value ...
                           inputValue.includes( ', ' +
                                                label.toLowerCase() + ',' );        // Find the normalized label in the normalized input.value ...

  Object.assign( attributes,
         attributes,
         { 'role':          'option',
           'id':            'awesomplete_list_' +
                            this.count +
                            '_item_' + item_id,
           'value':         value,                          // Give every option ( li ) a value attribute.
           'aria-selected': matched.toString() } );                 // If a match was found then set aria-selected to 'true'
                                                // else set area-selected to 'false'.

}
else {

  matched = false;

}

newTag = $.create( tagName );

    newTag.innerHTML = label;

if( text.attributes.length ) {

  // Now copy the attributes ...

  copyAttributes( text.attributes, newTag.attributes );

  // Add the rest of the attributes ...

  copyAttributes( attributes, newTag.attributes, true );

}

return newTag;
```